# TypeError: 'numpy.uint64' does not have the buffer interface

Tags: python, numpy, pycuda

i am using pycuda and i write this program

```
etat=np.zeros(XBLOCK * YBLOCK * XGRID * YGRID,dtype=np.uint)
compteur_init=np.uint(0)
clef_utilisateur=np.uint(SEED)
config=clef_utilisateur

compteur_init_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(compteur_init.nbytes)
etat_init_gpu=cuda.mem_alloc(etat.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(compteur_init_gpu, compteur_init)
cuda.memcpy_htod(etat_gpu, etat)
```

when i compile i get this error message

```
'numpy.uint64' does not have the buffer interface
```

what does it means exactly ??

Comment: Looks like there'a a typo in sample code, I'm sure you meant `cuda.memcpy_htod(etat_init_gpu, etat)`, note "_init_" bit.

Comment: Yes, sorry i've edited the code

Comment: the code seem to work when i put in comment those lines
`compteur_init_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(compteur_init.nbytes)

cuda.memcpy_htod(compteur_init_gpu, compteur_init)`
so i guess that the mistake come from the variable compteur_init

Answer (score 1):

finally , i've solved the problem with the module gpuarray

```
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
etat=np.zeros(XBLOCK * YBLOCK * XGRID * YGRID,dtype=np.uint)
etat_gpu= gpuarray.to_gpu(etat)

kern(etat_gpu,np.uint(10),block=(XBLOCK,YBLOCK,1),grid=(XGRID,YGRID,1))
```